# How to access iphone's file system?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to implement a program which is used to get access the file system of the iphone.My application is such a way that my resume is in my iphone and i want to upload it by accessing the file system..

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid You cannot be able to achieve this ..since apple is very much strict because of securities ,It provides sandboxing of app,means you will have only restricted access of file system and you cannot access files of other apps

Comment: Actually you are incorrect, you are allowed to use your iPhone for storage, but these files must be stored in /Library. The way most developers get around to transferring files is have the iOS Device temporary create a Webserver so a computer may upload files to the device. To see examples simply search "file storage"

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the filesystem. Except jail breaking.

Your app have access to app's local folders.

Comment: You can't access the file system DIRECTLY, but you are able to transfer files to the device by a means similar if not identical to HTTP File Transfer. Im sure if you are able to download from the device, but i know for a fact you can upload to the device